# Syntax for eager loading assets from multiple matrix block types

Tags: matrix, eager-loading

When eager loading assets from within a matrix block like so:

```
{% set blocks = entry.relatedCategory
                     .with([categoryBlocks.blockType.blockAssetField])
                     .all() %}
```

What is the correct way of specifying that there are multiple block types to load that asset field from within?

Do you list each one manually:

```
{% set blocks = entry.relatedCategory
                     .with([
                            categoryBlocks.blockType.blockAssetField
                            categoryBlocks.blockTypeAlt.blockAssetField
                          ])
                     .all() %}
```

or is there a regex style version available, something like:

```
{% set blocks = entry.relatedCategory
                     .with([
                            categoryBlocks.{blockType|blockTypeAlt}.blockAssetField
                           ])
                     .all() %}
```

I have found that wildcarding works:

```
{% set blocks = entry.relatedCategory
                     .with([categoryBlocks.*.blockAssetField])
                     .all() %}
```

but this is only usable if all the block types contain the field.

I have read the docs, and looked over previous "eager-loading" tagged questions but not found anything on this.

Any clarification would be much appreciated